# Cannot assign a value of type 'nil' to a value of type 'NSMutableArray'

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing swift code & having a simple problem.

I declared a `MSMutableArray`, under certain condition, I set it to `nil`:

```
 func doJob() -> NSMutableArray {
    var arr = NSMutableArray()
    arr = addContentToArray()
    if CRITICAL_CONDITION {
       //ERROR: Cannot assign a value of type 'nil' to a value of type 'NSMutableArray'
       arr = nil
    }
    return arr
}
```

But when I set `arr` to `nil`, I got compiler error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'nil' to a value of type 'NSMutableArray'
```

Why? How can I set it to nil then?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign `nil` only to optional variables. However, when you are letting the type to be inferred, the compiler doesn't know that you are planning to assign `nil` in the future:

```
var arr: NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()
```

However, the whole thing about assigning `nil` to a variable that has previously held an array seems a bit dirty to me. Maybe it would be easier to use a new variable?

You haven't posted your real code so we can't do a real review but:

```
if CRITICAL_CONDITION {
   arr = nil
}

return arr
```

can be more easily written as

```
if CRITICAL_CONDITION {
   return nil
}

return arr
```

That will solve the problem, too, because you won't need to reassign the variable. A different approach would be to use a second variable:

```
var result: NSArray? = array
if CRITICAL_CONDITION {
   result = nil
}

return result
```

or even better

```
let result = CRITICAL_CONDITION ? nil: array
return result;
```

The whole point of specifying when a variable cannot be `nil` (non-optional) is the fact that optional variables are dangerous and you have to check them for `nil` all the time. So, use optionals only for a short time, ideally one condition and then convert them to non-optional. In this case, use the non-optional as long as possible and only when you really need to assign `nil`, convert to optional (declare a second, optional variable).

Comment: Why is it dirty to assign nil to array? I have a function which returns nil if critical condition is met, otherwise return NSMutableArray. That's why I set nil to the array. Could you please explain more what makes it feel dirty in my case?

Comment: @user842225 Can you post the whole method? I can explain it.

Comment: Yes, I have post the whole function.